# Get referring url for Android or iOS installation

Tags: android, ios

We have several landing pages that link to Google Play and iOS App Store.  I would love to know the landing page that a person came from within the app code.  I have searched around and can't find any clear answer.  Lots of gray area.

I just want to access the landing page URL in Java or Swift.

I realize iOS and Android are two separate beasts.  But does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Firebase Dynamic Links this helps you create various links using various alternatives as shown in this quote from the official `Firebase` source:

> You create a Dynamic Link either by using the Firebase console, using a REST API, iOS or Android Builder API, or by forming a URL by adding Dynamic Link parameters to a domain specific to your app.

Then your app can access the link in code using `Java` or `Swift` and the link will work even if the user has your app already in their phone and you can set a logic to handle that too and the links are also automatically direct the user to `AppStore` or `PlayStore` depending on which device is used.

Dont worry about whether the link will work for both Android and iOS and you can use the api to access the link as this quote says.

> With Dynamic Links, your users get the best available experience for the platform they open your link on. If a user opens a Dynamic Link on iOS or Android, they can be taken directly to the linked content in your native app. If a user opens the same Dynamic Link in a desktop browser, they can be taken to the equivalent content on your website.
>   In addition, Dynamic Links work across app installs: if a user opens a Dynamic Link on iOS or Android and doesn't have your app installed, the user can be prompted to install it; then, after installation, your app starts and can access the link.

You can get [more information on dynamic links here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) and check if it will solve your problem.